# Testing after update: The plugin class `WyriHaximus\TwigView\Plugin` cannot be found

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I started update CakePHP 3.5 to 3.6, but when I try check my code by tests, i got error:

> InvalidArgumentException: The plugin class `Migrations\Plugin` cannot be found. Ensure your autoloader is correct.

After, I runed command `php composer.phar require --dev phpunit/phpunit:"^5.7|^6.0"`

Now a got next error:

> InvalidArgumentException: The plugin class `WyriHaximus\TwigView\Plugin` cannot be found. Ensure your autoloader is correct.

And I don't used this plugin before.

Also I used [this](https://github.com/cakephp/app/releases/tag/3.6.5) release files for update deprecated code

How I can fix it, and what could provoke this problem?

Full error:

```
3) App\Test\TestCase\Controller\CardsControllerTest::testEditPostError
InvalidArgumentException: The plugin class `WyriHaximus\TwigView\Plugin` cannot be found. Ensure your autoloader is correct.

C:\work\OSPanel\domains\project.loc\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\BaseApplication.php:127
C:\work\OSPanel\domains\project.loc\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\BaseApplication.php:95
C:\work\OSPanel\domains\project.loc\vendor\cakephp\bake\src\Plugin.php:50
C:\work\OSPanel\domains\project.loc\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\BaseApplication.php:154
C:\work\OSPanel\domains\project.loc\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Server.php:124
C:\work\OSPanel\domains\project.loc\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Server.php:82
C:\work\OSPanel\domains\project.loc\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\TestSuite\MiddlewareDispatcher.php:149
C:\work\OSPanel\domains\project.loc\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase.php:495
C:\work\OSPanel\domains\project.loc\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase.php:392
C:\work\OSPanel\domains\project.loc\tests\TestCase\Controller\CardsControllerTest.php:229
```

Thank you.

Comment: _"Also I used this release files for update deprecated code"_ what do you mean with this? Did you follow the [official migration guide](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/appendices/3-6-migration-guide.html)?

Comment: @Remul , in guide recommend for hide deprecated set `'errorLevel' => E_ALL ^ E_USER_DEPRECATED`, but i want to replace this code to new. On Github i found answer witch recomend replace code to new from releases *(bootsprap.php, webroot/index.php etc)* with save my custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have removed/commented `Plugin::routes();` line from your `config/routes.php` file.